# iTunes: auto ramping up/down to avoid dead air

Tags: itunes

As a simple solution to avoid [dead air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_air), I'd like to overlap each pair of consecutive songs in a playlist by ramping them down/up.

In effect this would be a poor man's DJ solution.

I wouldn't mind if it's entirely non-interactive, just so long as it is suitable for dinner parties, dance events, and the like. Indeed, the DJ software applications on the app store all seem to *require* an operator. Does an automatic solution exist, one that takes no more input than: 1. playlist, and 2. duration of overlap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iTunes playback preferences (**iTunes menu > Preferences… > Playback**), you can toggle crossfading, and set it to take anywhere from 1 to 12 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Funny how closely the feature you point to matches what I was seeking. This covers the "dinner" scenario perfectly, but not quite the "dance" scenario. If a song has a very long introduction, it would be nice to either specify a starting point or to trim it. I know QuickTime Pro used to have a trimming feature. I'm sure I could trim through iMovie then extract the audio track. A slimmer feature would be nice. That's a question for another time.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a trimming function within iTunes that works separately from the crossfade solution proposed by @timothymh. This would work better for your dance scenario. If you right-click a song and select Get Info, you get an info window about the song. Under the Options tab, you can set a start and stop point for each song.

As an example, here I've set this song to start 20 seconds from the beginning.

[image]

Comment: And I can enter the starting and stopping times in boxes? What luxury! I was about to give up on iTunes and seek a way to parse a list of the filenames and starting times to generate one gigantic output using ffmpeg. But seriously.. I wish the crossfade and the start/stop times were parameters of a playlist, not global parameters.